# How to render html in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I save text data in database usin text editor TinyMCE, when I tried to render to blade returning the same data in database. `$text = "<p>alsdkjalkdsja</p>"`

```
{{ $text }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this {!! $text !!} to render html

Comment: reference from laravel documentation :- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data